# In Haskell, why is map a separate function to fmap?

Tags: haskell

As far as I know, you can use `fmap` in place of `map` in all cases -- the following two are equivalent.

```
map (*2) [1..10]
fmap (*2) [1..10]
```

So, since they do the same thing, why does `map` even exist? Why can't `fmap` just be `map`? My guess is it's either for a historical reason, or for performance somehow.

Comment: I suppose you could write an expression that would have ambiguous type with `fmap`, but it would probably need to be crafted for this purpose. My guess is that it is just historical.

Comment: @DietrichEpp You're right - I didn't see that one.

Comment: I usually find these questions with a Google search rather than the SO search.